# Mysql trigger from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

So, I have a table A that each time a user sends an image, a record is created storing the time it was uploaded, the username of the user and the image number out of all the images uploaded over time.

I need to make a second table B that will store the amount of images uploaded per user and the user name. I need this table B to be updated when a new entry is generated in A.

I found that a trigger function can be created, nevertheless I'm having a rough time finding an example that will suit my needs.

Does anyone know a way of doin what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Just update `b` table with a select count of total inserted records on `a` from current user `NEW.userid` (userid is your column name or whatever name you have there, and NEW is a fixed mySql reference for the current values to be inserted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER img_sum AFTER INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW SET b.total =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE a.userid=NEW.userid)  
WHERE b.userid = NEW.userid;
```

Comment: THanks for the answer I ll chek it

Comment: What does the NEW parameter stand for?

Comment: is the reference to the inserted record values...ie: if you are inserting values for columns name, phone, you can access them by NEW.name, NEW.phone

Comment: I changed the total to count as it is my count row and I'm retrieving this error. Unknown system variable 'Count'

Comment: opps the select count was missing table name just repalce with: `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE a.userid=NEW.userid)`

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described i don't think you need a second table. You can just count the number of time a user name has occurred, and you will get the number of images that user has uploaded.

You can get the count doing something like that

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) FROM table_name;
```

If you still need to create 2 tables, you might want to take a look at procedures and how they work.

Comment: Thing is that I will empty the table every once in a while because It is sort of a weekly competition. How would you recommend me to do so with two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have 3 tables for this case:

```
- users(id, username, email ....), 
- user_images(id, userId, image_num, date_uploaded)
- user_images_count(id, user_name, images_count)
```

The `user_images_count` is initially empty. We have to fill it up by such query:

```
INSERT into user_images_count(user_name, images_count)
 SELECT (select username from users where ui.userId = id) as username, count(userId) as counter FROM `user_images` ui group by ui.userId;
```

Then, we must immediately create the trigger that will process every INSERT operation into `user_images` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `count_user_images` AFTER INSERT ON `user_images`
 FOR EACH ROW begin

declare u_name tinytext default "";
set u_name = (select username from users where id = NEW.userId limit 1);
if(u_name != "") then
    update user_images_count set images_count = images_count + 1 where user_name = u_name;
end if;
end
```

This two queries (user_images_count fulfillment and trigger creation must be performed in one transaction, one by one).
I've created similar triggers on my local databases. They work pretty good. )))

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' a

Comment: please, post the full query which throws the above error